# Merge rows after query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm having some issues in combining several rows.

Currently have this query:

```
SELECT TBLAgenda.ArtikelID, TBLArtikelen.ID, TBLArtikelen.Artikel,TBLAgenda.Plaats, TBLAgendaDatum.Datum, TBLAgendaDatum.Sessie
FROM TBLAgenda
INNER JOIN TBLArtikelen ON TBLAgenda.ArtikelID = TBLArtikelen.ID 
INNER JOIN TBLAgendaDatum ON TBLAgenda.AgendaID = TBLAgendaDatum.AgendaID
```

Now, each artikel is served in a place on certain dates.
The combo of artikel and Plaats is the key here. One artikel is used on different 'plaats'.

What I need is a way to display with Artikel, Plaats and all dates.

Currently this is a part of the result:

```
Windows 10 in TORHOUT op 2016-01-05 00:00:00
Bestandsbeheer in BRUGGE op 2016-01-07 00:00:00
Windows 10 in TORHOUT op 2016-01-12 00:00:00
Windows 10 in TORHOUT op 2016-01-19 00:00:00
Windows 10 in TORHOUT op 2016-01-26 00:00:00
Windows 10 in TORHOUT op 2016-02-02 00:00:00
Bestandsbeheer in BRUGGE op 2016-01-14 00:00:00
Bestandsbeheer in BRUGGE op 2016-01-21 00:00:00
Android Smartphone/Tablet in OOSTENDE op 2016-01-01 00:00:00
Android Smartphone/Tablet in OOSTENDE op 2016-01-12 00:00:00
Android Smartphone/Tablet in OOSTENDE op 2016-01-19 00:00:00
Android Smartphone/Tablet in OOSTENDE op 2016-01-26 00:00:00
Android Smartphone/Tablet in OOSTENDE op 2016-02-02 00:00:00
Android Smartphone/Tablet in BRUGGE op 2016-01-08 00:00:00
Android Smartphone/Tablet in BRUGGE op 2016-01-15 00:00:00
Android Smartphone/Tablet in BRUGGE op 2016-01-22 00:00:00
Android Smartphone/Tablet in BRUGGE op 2016-01-29 00:00:00
Android Smartphone/Tablet in BRUGGE op 2016-01-05 00:00:00
Windows 10 in GENT op 2016-01-20 00:00:00
Windows 10 in KORTRIJK op 2016-01-21 00:00:00
Windows 10 in KORTRIJK op 2016-01-28 00:00:00
Windows 10 in KORTRIJK op 2016-02-04 00:00:00
Windows 10 in BRUGGE op 2016-01-28 00:00:00
Windows 10 in BRUGGE op 2016-02-04 00:00:00
WindowsPhone in OOSTENDE op 2016-02-16 00:00:00
WindowsPhone in OOSTENDE op 2016-02-23 00:00:00
WindowsPhone in OOSTENDE op 2016-03-01 00:00:00
WindowsPhone in OOSTENDE op 2016-03-08 00:00:00
```

So I need to display:
Windows 10 - Torhout - 2016/01/05, 2016/01/12, 2016/01/19, 2016/01/26, 2016/02/02
Bestandsbeheer - Brugge - 2016/01/14, 2016/01/21
.......

Comment: Check out MySQL's `group_concat`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it rings a bell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `group_concat()` and `group by`:

```
SELECT ag.ArtikelID, ag.Plaats,
       GROUP_CONCAT(d.Datum) as datums
FROM TBLAgenda ag INNER JOIN
     TBLArtikelen ar ON ag.ArtikelID = ar.ID INNER JOIN
     TBLAgendaDatum d
     ON ag.AgendaID = d.AgendaID
GROUP BY ag.ArtikelID, ag.Plaats;
```

Note also that the use of table aliases makes the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Well, this is indeed what I needed. Thanks for this reply!